# Repeatedly use context manager inside a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a class so that a user can interact with an HDF5 file.  In the past I've had problems with HDF5 files being corrupted.  I think this happened because the file wasn't properly closed.  Because of this, I want all methods in the class that need to get data from the file to use a context manager.  I can think of several ways to to this.

##### Option 1

Just manually use the `with ... as ...` statement in every method that needs it.

##### Option 2

Create a decorator that opens the file.

```
def hdf_decorator(method_to_decorate):
    @functools.wraps(method_to_decorate)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        self = args[0] # rename to self
        args = args[1:] # pull out all the other args
        with h5py.File(self.filename,'r') as hdf:
            return method_to_decorate(self,hdf,*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper

class FileDoer:

    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filename = filename

    @hdf_decorator
    def fileReader(self,hdf,key):
        """
        A method for reading an HDF file.
        """
        return hdf[key][()]
```

This works, but is going to be confusing to a user (i.e. me tomorrow), because when you call the method, you don't include the hdf variable.  I don't really like it, but it does mean I'm always doing the same thing every time I use the decorator.

##### Option 3

Create protected / private methods that require the hdf variable and a public method that doesn't.  For example:

```
class FileDoer:

    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def publicMethod(self,key):
        """
        A public method for accessing the data in key.  User documentation here.
        """
        with h5py.File(self.filename,'r') as hdf:
            return self._protectedMethod(hdf,key)

    def _protectedMethod(self,hdf,key):
        """
        A protected method to do the work.
        """
        return hdf[key][()]
```

I'm writing a public / protected (or public / private) pair for each method that needs to access the file.  I'm not fond of that.

Which is a good design to use for this kind of data access class?  Something totally different?

Comment: one private method that takes a higher order function as a parameter and invokes it under the file manager? seems like the simplest solution to refactor the shared code

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "higher order function," but the rest of your comment seems like it might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Up to me?  I think option #1 is the one that'll make the most sense both to you and to whoever has to read your code in a year.

Comment: @Frank repeating the same code again and again might be easy to read, but has other downsides. Not motivated to write the sample code on my phone while on vacation, so hopefully someone else might.

Comment: I was saying that I think putting a single `with_hdf_file` inside of say `file_reader` was better than putting `@hdf_file` outside of it.  Same number of lines.  No duplication.  Just that the user wouldn't see the number of arguments magically change.